# fading through a stack of images(divs) with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, opacity

i am making an ipad web app for a museum.  the want to showcase the results from infrared and z-ray scans of famous paintings.  so i want to have fixed divs - stacked.  original/infrared/x-ray/more+  and to use the scroll bar to fade them out (smoothly) one by one.  i have gotten as far as this jsfiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/JDLqV/1/   but i'm worried i'm going about this the wrong way.  --- any ideas other directions i should be taking?  i haven't figured out how to get down to the third layer yet... thanks

Comment: I don't know how many images you will be displaying but you should definitely look into memory management. iOS' built-in Safari browser can run out of memory quite quickly when displaying large images and there doesn't seem to be an universal solution for it that works across all iOS versions.

Comment: Maybe you can just load two images and .remove(); the previous when the opacity of this one == 0 ??

Comment: i am just making the mock up to "sell" the clients boss on it... so i'll keep that memory thing in mind.  thanks.

Comment: as for the .remove... i used that in a few tests - but it doen't let the user control the fade... and this is for seeing subtle changes in the underpainting... like moving an arm slightly.  can't really get into it - if you're not in control of the fade... maybe i wasn't using  all of it's capabilities though...

Comment: Have you tested what you have so far on an iPad? If I'm not wrong, javascript is evaluated AFTER scroll, so you may have to account for this also.

Comment: ahren... i just tested it on ipad.. and you are correct... it evaluates after scroll... which is no good for me... hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

This will get you three levels deep: http://jsfiddle.net/JDLqV/2/

Could probably be refined to be more generic:

```
var divs = $('div.img:eq(2)');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var val = 1 - st/700; 
    if(val < 0){
        divs = $('div.img:eq(1)'); 
        val = 2 - st/700; 
    }else if(val > 0){
        divs = $('div.img:eq(2)'); 
    }
    divs.css({ 'opacity' : val  });
});
```

Comment: it works!  thanks for your time... unfortunately the ipad is not evaluating the scroll in realtime... which messes up my approach... but thank you.

Comment: @sheriffderek - No problem. Actually I thought your approach was ingenious considering the few lines code and the dramatic effect they produced (in a jsFiddle no less!). A shame it doesn't jive with the iPad, hopefully you'll find a more suitable approach.

Comment: i love simplicity!  i've been looking into turning off the safari scroll bar and using a jquery one and trying to hook into that... been distracted though.